# dg33bu + nVidia 210 weird issue

Tags: bios, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an old system with intel DG33BU. It has variety of issues now.

- Its IDE port do not work anymore
- Realtek audio rear port got short circuited.
- Front audio panel do not work

Now it has started giving a weird issue . 
if I do not connect my graphics card to complete the bios screen it takes about 10 mins.
If I connect my graphics card the bios screen complete immediately but windows 7 runs so slowly that I can see mouse trail.

I tried upgrading downgrading bios. Reinstalling windows 7.Removing any ide connection. trying to boot without any device connected.

So any other solution or time to dump my motherboard ?

Comment: Sounds like you should replace the entire computer.

Comment: lol.All the problems only in motherboard . I think replacing that would just do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a problem with the SMPS..

Even I am wondering how an SMPS could make the system slow..

I got an old SMPS for testing and the PC works absolutely fine now..